# Support mobile safe-area in Docusaurus v2-site

Tags: docusaurus

Is there any way to configure Docusaurus v2 to use the safe-area for mobile phone? I'd like to stretch a footer and header in landscape-mode to avoid the white bars on iPhones etc.

In pure HTML this typically requires modifying `viewport` meta-tag to also specify `viewport-fit=cover` and applying the required padding etc in CSS to avoid conflicts with camera, menubar etc.

In Docusaurus-docs I only see modifying [ssrTemplate](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#ssrTemplate) as an option, but that feels very complex (and additional maintenance?) just to modify a hardcoded meta-tag. I tried the following, but it creates a duplicate meta-tag instead of updating it.

```
 themeConfig: {
    metadata: [
        {
            name: 'viewport',
            content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusaurus v2.1.0 makes `viewport` meta-tag customizable through themeConfig (shown in question) and through plugins.

See https://docusaurus.io/blog/2022/09/01/docusaurus-2.1#overriding-default-meta-tags